# can not add referance to vb6 project

Tags: c#, vb6

I have a classlibrary project written with c#.net, and I want to add this project dll to a new
vb6 project, but I can not do this.

When I try to add reference to my vb6 project it say

`cannot add reference to specified file`

Note I have registered the dll 
using: `regsvr32 project.dll`

Comment: You need to register typelib of your .NET project. Search for regasm examples.

Comment: You cannot register a C# assembly with Regsvr32.exe, that generates an error message.  Using Regasm.exe is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Regasm.exe from the Visual Studio Command Line with the switch to create a typelib file:

```
regasm.exe MyAssembly.dll /tlb /codebase
```

Then in VB6 you reference the .tlb file that is created after running Regasm.